# Скриншот текущего активного окна

Tags: wpf, c#

В моем WPF приложении в определенной ситуации необходимо сделать скриншот текущего активного окна(в приложении может быть несколько открытых окон). Пока что получилось лишь сделать скриншот всего экрана.

Подскажите, как можно реализовать данный функционал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прочтите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/). Если вкопаться вглубь, то делается через WinAPI старым добрым способом. Если вместо handle передать 0, то вы получите весь экран.

```
// get te hDC of the target window
IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
// get the size
User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
// create a device context we can copy to
IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
// create a bitmap we can copy it to,
// using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc,width,height); 
// select the bitmap object
IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hBitmap);
// bitblt over
GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest,0,0,width,height,hdcSrc,0,0,GDI32.SRCCOPY);
// restore selection
GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hOld);
// clean up 
GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
User32.ReleaseDC(handle,hdcSrc);
// get a .NET image object for it
Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
// free up the Bitmap object
GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать это средствами С# и WPF, возможно существует способ?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, .NET не имеет способов делать что-то такое. Поэтому приходится использовать WinAPI.

Answer (score 3):

с помощью RenderTargetBitmap можно вывести wpf-контрол в виде рисунка.

пример взят [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189179).

```
UserControl control = new UserControl1();
control.Measure(new Size(300, 300));
control.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(300,300)));

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(300, 300, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(control);

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"c:\test.png"))
   encoder.Save(stm);
```